# Is there a way to get coordinates when plotting with tkplot?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, tkplot

I am wondering if it is in some way possible to visualize a network with tkplot() function, move the nodes in a desired position and then get the coordinates of this position of nodes? Have you ever done this? Or what could be another way if I do not know a specific position before plotting and want to see the result at first and only after decide the position. This would save a lot of time of trying to find the best coordinates by inserting numbers. Thanks!

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://igraph.org/r/doc/tkplot.html. Specifically you will want `tk_coords()`

Comment: tk_coords() is what I was looking for, thanks!